# Adding new objects to an ArrayList in constructor

Tags: java, class, object, arraylist

I am trying to add newly created objects to an ArrayList in the constructor of a class. The new objects are being created in another class in the main method.

Main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Player p1 = new Player("Peter");
}
```

My Player class:

```
public class Player {

protected static int age;
protected static String name;
protected static ArrayList players = new ArrayList();

Player(String aName) {
    
    name = aName;
    age = 15;
    players.add(new Player()); // i know this doesn't work but trying along these lines
    
   }
}
```

Comment: `name` and `age` should not be static.

Comment: You could try `players.add(this)` which refers to your current instance, but I my suggestion would be to revise your structure because I think it should not be the Player's duty to remember which players have been created so far. This functionality should be delegated to a dedicated entity

Comment: There could be legitamate reasons to keep a list of all players inside Player. I'm not saying I would do it this way, but you can make a perfectly workable program like this

Comment: I agree, there is always the possibility. I can't know what his exact thoughts are, but following his example and the usage of the static variables, I reached the above conclusion

Comment: It almost looks like a implementation of a linked list that uses `ArrayList` instead of `Player previous;Player next` I would bet that there will be a method `next` & `previous`. Otherwise I agree with @Grove that it should be delegated elsewhere

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to edit the line

```
players.add(new Player());
```

to

```
players.add(this);
```

Also, there is no need to make the age and name static

I suggest you should have the following code instead

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Player {

protected int age;    //static is removed
protected String name;  // static is removed
protected static ArrayList<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();  //this is not a best practice to have a list of player inside player.

Player(String aName) {

    name = aName;
    age = 15;
    players.add(this); // i know this doesn't work but trying along these lines

   }


public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Player p1 = new Player("Peter");
}


}
```

Comment: Just adding a default constructor would lead to creation of a player having a **different** new player added to the arraylist, the OP is using new Player() to explain the concept of "this"

Comment: I managed to do it in the end and it was exactly along these lines. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're *actually* asking how to refer to the instance you're constructing.
That's what the `this` keyword does.

Comment: no. he is failing cause `new Player()` wont work, due to no default constructor.

Comment: @DarthVader: Yes, but that doesn't make sense anyway.

Comment: @DarthVader I think the OP is using new Player() to express the concept of "this"

Comment: I think there is a design and understanding the concepts problem there. such as static props, and Player has players didnt make much sense to me

Answer (score 0):

This post is old, but for someone with similiar needs I suggest doing it like this:

Main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //TODO code application logic here
    java.util.List<Player> players = new java.util.ArrayList<>(); //list to hold all players
    Player p1 = new Player("Peter"); //test player
    players.add(p1); //adding test player to the list
    players.add(new Player("Peter")); //also possible in this case to add test player without creating variable for it.
}
```

Player class:

```
public class Player {

    private final int age = 15; //if you always going to use 15 as a age like in your case it could be final. if not then pass it to constructor and initialize the same way as the name.
    private String name;

    Player(String name) { //variable name can be the same as one in class, just add this prefix to indicated you are talking about the one which is global class variable.
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Generally you should avoid using static keyword on variables which supposed to be different in each instance of that class. Avoid having object of itself inside.